# Dynamic dropdown from mysql database in PHP and display the related data in the table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am stuck at this point.

Dynamic dropdown list from MySQL and when user selects an item the data related to that item should be displayed in the html page dynamically in a tabular format.

**Note:** I am able to read the data dynamically in the dropdown box but I am not getting how to display the data related to the selected dropdown list in a tabular format.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","apps");

if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo $con->connect_error;
    die("sorry database connection fails..);
}

$combo .= "<select>";
$sql = "SELECT unam FROM users";

if ($result = $con->query($sql)) {
   if ($result->num_rows) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
         $combo .= "<option>".$row->unam."</option";
      }
      
      $result->free();
   }
}

$combo .= "</select>";
echo $combo;

?>
```

Comment: Try to replace $combo.="<select>"; with $combo="<select>";

Comment: you have a syntax error here `die("sorry database connection fails..);` if that's your REAL code.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the value

```
$combo.="<option value=".$row->unam.">".$row->unam."</option>";
```

after you replace

```
$combo .= "<select>";
```

by

```
 $combo = "<select>";
```